# rspec issue "invalid option: --autotest (OptionParser::InvalidOption)"

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I keep getting an issue with rspec when I

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

```
/Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:18:in `parse!': invalid option: --autotest (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:4:in `parse!'
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:104:in `options_from'
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:100:in `global_options'
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:65:in `parse_options'
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `run'
        from /Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@hub/gems/rspec-core-2.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.  I have tried uninstalling my gems and reinstalling them.  I've tried different versions of rspec2.  The same application's specs used to work for me.  I have no idea what might have changed that introduced this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have this option defined in `./.rspec`?:

`--autotest`

If so, remove it.

**EDIT**

<strike>Autotest is now configured in `./autotest/discover.rb`, which should contain:</strike>

```
Autotest.add_discovery { "rails" }
Autotest.add_discovery { "rspec2" }
```

Seems this is no longer necessary. See David's answer

Comment: In my project folder `--autotest` was not included in `./.rspec`, but I forgot that I had a global .rspec in `~/.rspec`.  In my `~/.rspec` file I did have `--autotest`.  Now that I removed `--autotest` from my global .rspec, everything works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't even need that. All you need is a `.rspec` file in the project root directory (it can have options or be empty) to add the "rspec2" discovery, and "rails" gets discovered based on a rails-like directory structure.

Comment: I removed the ./autotest/discover.rb file and everything seems to work well.